# How to change pagination text “Next” “Previous” to Icon or arrow in laravel

Tags: laravel, frontend

i try to add simplePaginate by laravel in controller, and it show “Next” “Previous” button, i want to changes into arrow button, how to change that? if there a bootstrap css, where the css is located?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

Answer (score 1):

The pagination of laravel is a build-in function.

The easiest way to customize the pagination views is by running this command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

This command will place the views in the *resources/views/vendor/pagination* directory. modify the ***bootstrap-4.blade.php*** file to change the default pagination

More information on this subject can be found here:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

Answer (score 0):

Laravel includes pagination views built using Tailwind CSS. To use these views instead of the default Bootstrap views, you may call the paginator's useTailwind method within your `AppServiceProvider`:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

public function boot()
{
    Paginator::useTailwind();
}
```

Change to :

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
    
public function boot()
{
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
}
```